# Typescript convention name file and folders

Tags: typescript

I have TypeScript project and I don't know which convention that it is better to use in oder to name the folders and files.

The files contains one `class` or several `export functions`.

Comment: You choose the convention you like the most. If you work in a team, talk about it with your team.

Comment: I have spoken on the team but anybody know. We have started to use for the Class file the PascalCase and for the others the kebab-case, but I don't know if it is a good idea.

Comment: Why should we be the judges of how you name files? Stack Overflow isn't really a place to ask for *opinions*.

Comment: I wish to find a rules like for Java. But I have not found it! I'm not asking the opinions, I'm asking the rules.

Comment: There are no rules.

Comment: Ah ok Thanks, so it si possible to have PascalCase for class file and kebabCase for the others?